# What made SVB Bank to be uniquely negatively affected by higher interest rates?

Tags: interest-rates, banks

For normal banks, higher interests means more profits. Why is SVB Bank the opposite?

Comment: This thread may interest you https://twitter.com/FabiusMercurius/status/1634227592227336195 In essence: due to unusual circumstances SVB was forced to sell Bonds it owned at a loss. (When i.r. rise the mrket price of Bonds goes down).

Comment: Other Banks may also hold "underwater Bonds", but as long as they don't have to sell them, they should be alright https://twitter.com/Brad_Setser/status/1634308556261412864 Still, it is a bit concerning, isn't it ? What other big bondholders could get in trouble?

Comment: An article in the FT `Silicon Valley Bank is a very American mess` is also interesting (please Google). It is about the regulatory aspects.

Comment: @nbbo2 I'm not opposed to closing the question as inappropriate, but "too basic" is rather hard to accept. There are significant risk management issues involving interest rate exposure and correlations between SVB's asset values and funding liquidity. This isn't "basic."

Comment: OK, I agree.  SVB may well become a Case Study for advanced Management of Financial Institutions courses in the future.  (The more I read about it the more complex it seems). I will delete my comment. You can vote to re-open if you want.

Comment: A good WSJ article: https://www.wsj.com/amp/articles/wall-street-braces-for-the-next-silicon-valley-bank-956b8f03

Comment: Bill Ackman's tweet: https://twitter.com/BillAckman/status/1634564398919368704

Comment: A good FT article: https://www.ft.com/content/0e1c671f-7998-4a55-a44e-edf07193616d